# Laravel api call fails

Tags: php, laravel, api, vue.js, laravel-5.6

So I asked this question in larachat and searched in google. I know that similar questions have been asked before but none of them worked for me.

I'm trying to load the comment's of a `post` but the request doesn't even get to the `api.php` here is the request I do:

```
axios.get(`/api/posts/${this.post.id}/comments`)
```

and than I have this inside the api.php:

```
Route::get('/posts/{id}/comments', function(){
     return "got here";
});
```

But I get the error: ***`GET http://localhost/api/posts/2/comments 404 (Not Found)`***

Even when I manually try to access the api with: `http://localhost/api/posts/2/comments`

I still get the ***`The requested URL /api/posts/2/comments was not found on this server.`***
I don't know if i can access it that way but I tried.

I run php `artisan route:list` and I get it in the list like this:

`GET|HEAD      | api/posts/{id}/comments |                    | Closure                                                                    | api                 |`

Comment: are you sure that `http://localhost/` is where your laravel app is hosted? what do you see when you visit `http://localhost/` ?

Comment: Try to set APP_URL properly in .env file first.

Comment: @JacobGoh no it's inside the `lexicon` and than `/public`

Comment: @AbidRaza my hompage url is `http://localhost/lexicon/public/home` so should I set `APP_URL` as: `APP_URL=http://localhost/lexicon` instead of : `APP_URL=http://localhost`

Comment: Just wondering if you are sure that it's serving your site on port 80? Are you using `php artisan serve` ?

Comment: @Ikbel No I'm using wamp

Comment: You should use virtual host to avoid such problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the application in localhost then your url must be http://localhost/projectfolder/public/api/posts/2/comments

Have a base url that contains http://localhost/projectfolder/public/api/. Then you can call url by adding the base url with them

Comment: in JQuery it's pretty easy to give the links like `var url = '{{ route("url") }}';`  can you show me how I can give the url so it will work in actuall server too?

Comment: In actual server you will be pointing the domain to the extend public folder. You don't have to worry in actual server. Because the domain will be pointing to the public folder. Then this /api/posts/${this.post.id}/comments will work as it is. In local just run the application with PHP artisan serve to make the application to run in seperate port like http://localhost:8000 then you don't have to change the code.

Comment: so you are saying that, I have no chance of getting to that url with wamp? because when i tried it manually. the link works as `http://localhost/lexicon/public/api/posts/2/comments`